# Installing a SonarQube Plugin Programmatically

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I have a SonarQube service and API deployed in containers as part of my build pipeline. The SonarQube service needs to have the SonarJava plugin installed to understand my code rules.

As it's not an option to manually install this plugin, I'd like to do it through the API.

I saw this post: [How to install or uninstall SonarQube plug-ins with HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205334/how-to-install-or-uninstall-sonarqube-plug-ins-with-http) which seemed helpful, however attempting `"POST /api/plugins/install?key=SonarJava"` hasn't led to much success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SonarJava is pre-installed in new instances, and you shouldn't have to re-install it for each analysis. This is probably actually an issue of how your container is configured.

Comment: That's interesting. When I push in my java based rules at startup with my sonarapi service on a bare sonar instance, the rules all fail. When I do the same, but with the sonarjava.jar~ file put into ../extensions/plugins at at startup, everything goes as expected.

Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Does Sonar require a project to run before it downloads the sonarjava plugin and thus understands the rules it's given?

Comment: On a new instance SonarJava is in place by default, and that's the case with upgrades starting with SQ 7.2.

Comment: I see. I'm using SQ 6.7.4, so I guess that would explain why it wasn't there by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `/api/plugins/install?key=java`, it will automatically install `SonarJava` plugins.